Extracting coefficients from a list of expressions
I have a list of the form,
mylist = {
(1. + 1. I) myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + (2. - 3. I) myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + (1. - 3. I) Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2, 
(1. - 1. I) myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + (4. - 3. I) myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + (-1. - 2. I) Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2, 
(1. + 1. I) myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + (-2. - 4. I) myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + (1 + 3 I) Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2
}

In the above list, each element is a sum of polynomial of the same two variables.
In particular, this means that the list can be written as
mylistOrganised = list1 myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + list2 myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + list3 Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2,

where
list1 = {1. + 1. I, 1. - 1. I, 1. + 1. I};
list2 = {2. - 3. I, 4. - 3. I, -2. - 4. I};
list3 = {1. - 3. I, -1. - 2. I, 1. + 3. I};

It is simple to find list1, list2, list3, for example via,
list1 = D[myexpr, myA[2, 2, 0], myA[2, 2, 0]]/2;

etc.
I would like to automate this process by defining a function myfn that takes myexpr as input and outputs
myfn[myexpr]
(* Output: {{list1, myA[2, 2, 0]^2},{list2, myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[
 myB[2, -2, 0]]},{list3, Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2}} *)

The code needs to be sufficiently general in the following way:
In myexpr, the two variables that appear are myA[2, 2, 0] and Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]. In general however, they can be either of myA[l1,m1,n1], myB[l2,m2,n2], Conjugate[myA[l1,-m1,n1]], Conjugate[myB[l2,-m2,n2]], for integer valued l1,l2,m1,m2,n1,n2.
There is a nice answer to a similar problem in the StackExchange post, but 1) it is not clear how this extends when we are dealing with a list as in my case (so where the final "coefficients" are actually lists), and 2) FactorTermsList does not seem to work for floating numbers.

What have you tried? This is not the Mechanical Turk stackexchange.

Here's an automated solution that detects the relevant variables in the expression:
myfn[expr_List] := Module[
   {vars = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _myA | _myB | Conjugate[_myA] | Conjugate[_myB], Infinity]},
   vars = Apply[{#2, Times @@ (vars^#1)} &, Transpose@CoefficientRules[expr, vars], {2}];
   {#[[All, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} & /@ vars
 ]

Then:
mylist = {
(1. + 1. I) myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + (2. - 3. I) myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + (1. - 3. I) Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2, 
(1. - 1. I) myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + (4. - 3. I) myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + (-1. - 2. I) Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2, 
(1. + 1. I) myA[2, 2, 0]^2 + (-2. - 4. I) myA[2, 2, 0] Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] + (1 + 3 I) Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2
}

and
myfn[mylist]
{{{1 - 3 I, -1 - 2 I, 1 + 3 I}, Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]]^2},
 {{2 - 3 I, 4 - 3 I, -2 - 4 I}, Conjugate[myB[2, -2, 0]] myA[2, 2, 0]},
 {{1 + I, 1 - I, 1 + I}, myA[2, 2, 0]^2}}

